# Inserting large amounts of binary data into SQL Server

Tags: script, sql-server, sql

I am scripting a few hundred binary files into a table in a MS SQL Server database, where the binary data as such will be entered into one column, and some meta data into others.

The files total at something like 150 MB and Management Studio just won't let me run it. For reasons yet unknown, `sqlcmd` from the shell does not work (I don't think I have permissions to configure the server accordingly).

And so I'm lost in regards to finding a good approach.

With `sqlcmd` probably out of question, is there a way I can get around to doing this, without resorting to splitting every of the ~300 files into separate queries, and running them manually? That prospect is horrendous.

Comment: Have you looked at using something like `BULK INSERT` and delimited text?

Comment: Looking at it now and trying to understand. Thanks.